# Do we need wal_keep_segments when we have archive_command?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to clarify some concepts about how `archive_command` in conjunction with `wal_keep_segments`

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

`wal_keep_segments`: if slaves fall behind `wal_keep_segments` then downstream connections will fail and we have to recovery all downsteam connections (slaves)

`archive_command`: if slaves lag behind `wal_keep_segments` (excess) then pg start to purge oldest segment in `pg_wall/`to `archive/`

If two above statements are correct, does pg always wait for `wal_keep_segments` `excess` before doing purge segment to `archive_command`? that mean downstreams need to always failed.

in `recovery.conf`, I have:

```
restore_command = 'cp /var/lib/postgresql/11/main/archive/%f %p'
```

does that mean I don't need to set `wal_keep_segments` if I've set `archive_command`?

Edit: I need to clarify some questions:

1. does file under `archive/` folder auto rotate by pg? or we need crontab to clean it up?
2. in case of disaster, we can manually recovery from `archive/`, I wonder does we really need to set `wal_keep_segments` to non-zero number? (or keep it default to zero so all segments will be put in `archive`?
3. if we set both `wal_keep_segments` and `archive_command`, does pg wait till segments excess `wal_keep_segments` before purging to `archive/` or does it purge immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> wal_keep_segments: if slaves fall behind wal_keep_segments then downstream connections will fail and we have to recovery all downsteam connections (slaves)

I don't know what you mean by "we have to recovery".  Recovery is what the standbys are normally doing.  If they can't continue recovery because there is permanently missing WAL, then what you have to do is **recreate** them, not recover them.

> archive_command: if slaves lag behind wal_keep_segments (excess) then
>   pg start to purge oldest segment in pg_wall/to archive/

If archive_mode is on, then archive_command gets run.  The setting of wal_keep_segments doesn't matter to archive_command. The files get purged only once checkpoint is satisfied *and* archive_command (if in use) is satisfied *and* wal_keep_segments is satisfied *and* all replication slots (if in use) are satisfied.

> in recovery.conf, I have:
>
> ```
> restore_command = 'cp /var/lib/postgresql/11/main/archive/%f %p'
> ```
>
> does
>   that mean I don't need to set wal_keep_segments if I've set
>   archive_command?

Correct.  It can fall back on the archive if it falls too far behind, so wal_keep_segments is not needed.

> does file under archive/ folder auto rotate by pg? or we need crontab to clean it up?

PostgreSQL doesn't even know that the archive/ folder exists.  That is part of your archive_command.  PostgreSQL just executes the archive_command after replacing the % variables.  It doesn't parse and understand that command.  You have to decide how long to keep the files in archive/, and then implement that decision.

> in case of disaster, we can manually recovery from archive/,

Yes, provided that you have an eligible base backup, and that the 'archive/' did not get destroyed by whatever disaster destroyed the rest of your server.

(Or, you could promote your standby to be the new master, if that is what your disaster recovery plan is--there are multiple ways to design things)

> if we set both wal_keep_segments and archive_command, does pg wait till segments excess wal_keep_segments before purging to archive/ or does it purge immediately?

No.  It calls archive_command immediately after finishing the segment, regardless of what wal_keep_segments is set to.

Answer (score 2):

No, `wal_keep_segments` and `archive_command` are independent from each other.

As soon as a WAL segment is finished, it will be archived, no matter how `wal_keep_segments` is set. `wal_keep_segments` keeps the file from being deleted at the next checkpoint after it has been archived.

Comment: Sorry, I've missed that, `Does that mean I don't need to set wal_keep_segments if I've set archive_command`?

Comment: That question makes no sense, since there is no direct connection between these parameters. Sorry if I misunderstood (and mis-edited) the question. Can you explain that in more detail?

Comment: `archive_command` is normally only used on the primary. It does not purge WAL archives, it writes them.

Comment: Will pg wait till `wal_keep_segments` excess before cp oldest segment to `archieve/`?

Comment: Ok, I got it. Answer edited.